# How to efficiently link child nodes from the SKS with code in the scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm working on a side scroller game, I'm currently linking my nodes from the sks with classes like so. However, I'm sure there must be a cleaner more efficient way to do this as I can see this list getting colossal with more nodes added. What is a more efficient way to link up nodes with classes? Thanks in advance for the help !

```
    if (self.childNode(withName: "TheCamera") != nil){
        theCamera = self.childNode(withName: "TheCamera") as! SKCameraNode
        self.camera = theCamera
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "button") != nil){
        button = self.childNode(withName: "button") as! SKSpriteNode
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "shootButton") != nil){
        shootButton = self.childNode(withName: "shootButton") as! SKSpriteNode
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "leftButton") != nil){
        leftButton = self.childNode(withName: "leftButton") as! SKSpriteNode
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "rightButton") != nil){
        rightButton = self.childNode(withName: "rightButton") as! SKSpriteNode
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "Key") != nil) {
        theKey = self.childNode(withName: "Key") as! Key
        theKey.setUpKey()
    }
    if (self.childNode(withName: "lifeBar") != nil) {
        theLifeBar = self.childNode(withName: "lifeBar") as! LifeBar
        theLifeBar.setUp()
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "health")) != nil {
        theHealthPack = self.childNode(withName: "health") as! HealthPack
        theHealthPack.setUp()
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "Weapon") != nil) {
        theWeapon = self.childNode(withName: "Weapon") as! Weapon
        theWeapon.setUpWeapon()
    }

    if (self.childNode(withName: "Weapon2") != nil) {
        theWeapon = self.childNode(withName: "Weapon2") as! Weapon
        theWeapon.setUpWeapon()
    }


    if (self.childNode(withName: "knife_count") != nil) {
        knife_count = self.childNode(withName: "knife_count") as! SKLabelNode
    }
```

Comment: Generally it’s not necessary to have a property for every node in your screen. You can iterate overs node using `childNodeWithName` and other methods to connect to nodes only when required. Buttons can be picked up in `touchesBegan()` using `nodeAt(point:)`.

Comment: I usually break up the objects in to categories (not more optimized but makes it more readable in code) setupButtons, setupLabels, setupHero etc. it not necessary to check if each one in nil. you can use`if let weapon = self.childNode(withName: "weapon" as? Weapon { self.weapon = weapon }` again not more optimized just another way of writing it

Comment: @SteveIves thanks for your help, i'm refactoring the button into the touchesBegan()  accordingly.

Comment: @RonMyschuk thanks for that, i think your way makes it much more readable, i've refactored the objects so that i don't check if each one is nil, much better now !

Comment: @SteveIves, ouch, performance hitter, hyper0009 use can lazy var, but I hear in  Swift 4 this is changing again.  `lazy var knife_count = {return self.childNode(withName: "knife_count") as? SKLabelNode}()`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon You’ve lost me - what’s a performance hitter?

Comment: @SteveIves searching for a node everytime you need it

Comment: Well, yeah. If you need it regularly then pick it up as a property in `didMove(toView:)`, as the same for any other regularly-used nodes.  Tu he doesn’t need a property for every sprite in his scene.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks for your input, we tried that and used it for some of our nodes that we only wanted to use when needed. Nice one !

Comment: 3 people taking time to comment but nobody thinks this question is worthy of a +1 for a new user =/??

Comment: @Fluidity cheerio :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of these properties are a fundamental part of your game, and you do indeed need them defined as properties, then you can skip the check for `Nil`, because if they are not in your .sks file, then something has gone wrong, so you might want the game to crash.

You usually don't need a property for buttons, because you can check which button has been 'pressed' in `touchesBegan()` as follows:

```
    let touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self)
        if let touchedNode = self.nodes(at: touchLocation).first as SKSpriteNode
           {
            if let nodeName = touchedNode.name {
                switch nodeName {
                case "shootButton":
                    firePlayerMissile()

                case "leftButton":
                    ship.moveLeft()

                case "rightButton":
                    ship.moveRight()

                case "pauseButton":
                    pauseGame()

                default :
                    break
            }
        }
```

This should get your code simplified as follows:

```
self.camera = self.childNode(withName: "TheCamera") as! SKCameraNode

theKey = self.childNode(withName: "Key") as! Key
theKey.setUpKey()

theLifeBar = self.childNode(withName: "lifeBar") as! LifeBar
theLifeBar.setUp()

theHealthPack = self.childNode(withName: "health") as! HealthPack
theHealthPack.setUp()

theWeapon = self.childNode(withName: "Weapon") as! Weapon
theWeapon.setUpWeapon()

theWeapon = self.childNode(withName: "Weapon2") as! Weapon
theWeapon.setUpWeapon()

knife_count = self.childNode(withName: "knife_count") as! SKLabelNode
```

which doesn't look too bad.

Comment: Cheers ! I realised I was checking for the button press in the touchesBegan and setting properties for them in the didMoveToView; which as you said wasn't needed ! I removed them from the didMoveToView and works fine. Thank you.